# React custom hook not rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, remix.run

I am building an app with React using Remix, fly.io for deployment. I have a custom React hook `useCountdown` that has the following code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useCountdown = (targetSeconds) => {
    const countDownSeconds = targetSeconds

    const [countDown, setCountDown] = useState(countDownSeconds);

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setCountDown(countDownSeconds);

            return () => clearInterval(interval);
        }, [countDownSeconds]);

        return getReturnValues(countDown);
    }, [])
};

const getReturnValues = (countDown) => {
    const seconds = Math.floor((countDown % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    return [seconds];
}

export { useCountdown }
```

The `DateTimeDisplay` component has the following code and is a component dependency of the hook:

```
import React from 'react';

const DateTimeDisplay = ({ value, type, isDanger }) => {
    return (
        <div className={isDanger ? 'countdown danger' : 'countdown'}>
            <p>{value}</p>
            <span>{type}</span>
        </div>
    );
};

export default DateTimeDisplay;
```

Finally, I have a `CountdownTimer` component that has the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import DateTimeDisplay from './DateTimeDisplay';
import ExpiredNotice from './ExpiredNotice'
import { useCountdown } from '../hooks/useCountdown';


const ShowCounter = ({ seconds }) => {
    return (
        <div className="show-counter">
                <DateTimeDisplay value={seconds} type={'seconds'} isDanger={false} />
        </div>
    );
};

const CountdownTimer = ({ targetSeconds }) => {
    const [seconds] = useCountdown(targetSeconds);

    if (seconds <= 0) {
        return <ExpiredNotice />;
    } else {
        return (
            <ShowCounter
                seconds={seconds}
            />
        );
    }
};

export default CountdownTimer;
```

Upon trying to utilize the `useCountdown()` hook, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: useCountdown is not a function or its return value is not iterable
    at CountdownTimer (/Users/tduke/Desktop/dev/drawesome/app/components/CountdownTimer.jsx:17:23)
    at processChild (/Users/tduke/Desktop/dev/drawesome/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3353:14)
    at resolve (/Users/tduke/Desktop/dev/drawesome/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3270:5)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (/Users/tduke/Desktop/dev/drawesome/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3753:22)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (/Users/tduke/Desktop/dev/drawesome/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3690:29)
    at renderToString (/Users/tduke/Desktop/dev/drawesome/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:4298:27)
    at handleRequest (/Users/tduke/Desktop/dev/drawesome/app/entry.server.jsx:10:16)
    at handleDocumentRequest (/Users/tduke/Desktop/dev/drawesome/node_modules/@remix-run/server-runtime/server.js:400:18)
    at requestHandler (/Users/tduke/Desktop/dev/drawesome/node_modules/@remix-run/server-runtime/server.js:49:18)
    at /Users/tduke/Desktop/dev/drawesome/node_modules/@remix-run/express/server.js:39:22
```

The line in question:

```
    const [seconds] = useCountdown(targetSeconds);
```

1. Can someone explain to me this error, and what it exactly is telling me so I understand this error in it's entirety, and what the cause is in this instance?
2. How do I fix it?

Comment: We'll need to see `useCountdown` to tell you for sure. But the error is saying you can't use array destructuring (ie, the square brackets in `const [seconds] =`) because you didn't return an array.

Comment: @NicholasTower I apologize, I am new to Mac and I didn't correctly copy/paste the code. I fixed it and updated the post, if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useCountdown` does not have a return statement, so it's implicitly returning `undefined`. Then when you try to destructure `undefined`, you get that error because array destructuring only works on arrays (or other iterables, which is why the error mentions "iterable"s, not arrays)

You did put a return statement inside your useEffect, but returning something in a useEffect is for cleaning up the effect. It won't cause `useCountdown` to return anything. To fix this, move your return statement to the body of `useCountdown`, and move the effect cleanup to be the return from the effect:

```
const useCountdown = (targetSeconds) => {
    const countDownSeconds = targetSeconds

    const [countDown, setCountDown] = useState(countDownSeconds);

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setCountDown(countDownSeconds);
        }, [countDownSeconds]);

        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [])

    return getReturnValues(countDown);
};
```